# How to get rid of vertical hover gaps in a wrapped anchor tag?

Tags: css, typography

When I hover over the anchor tag, it flickers. It's because there are vertical gaps between the lines of the wrapped anchor tag. Moreover, if I happen to click between the lines, the link doesn't activate. I would like to get rid of this flickering and vertical hover gaps that cause it. The rest of the layout including apparent line height and button position (on the same line as the last word of the anchor tag) should stay the same.

I was thinking about this for a couple of days with no luck. The best alternative I have is using inline-block on the anchor tag, but that clears the button to the next line, which wastes too much space.

```css
body {
  line-height: 1.5;
  width: 300px;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
<p>
  <a href="#">Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </a>
  <button>click</button>
</p>
<p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added:

```
a {
   padding: 4px 0;
}
```

It'll give the `a` element an extra space from `top` and `bottom`, and it doesn't affect the `gaps`.

```css
body {
  line-height: 1.5;
  width: 300px;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 4px 0;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
<p>
  <a href="#">Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </a>
  <button>click</button>
</p>
<p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

Comment: Any explanation on why this works? Thanks.